# undefined local variable or method with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to create a simple search form in my Rails application. I get an error with the url path of the form:

```
<%= form_tag(med_search, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control" %>
            <%= button_to "Search", class: "btn btn-default" %>
          <% end %>
```

The first line above causes error `undefined local variable or method`med_search' for #<#:0x007fab2b5afa90>`

The problem is most likely with my routes setup. I created a new controller action called search so I edited my routes.db to look like this:

```
resources :meds do
  collection do
    get 'search' => 'meds#search'
  end
end
  devise_for :users
  #get 'meds/index'
  root to: "meds#index"
  resources :meds, :path => ''
end
```

When I do rake routes, I am seeing the path med search so I know the url is valid:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
              med_search GET    /meds/:med_id/search(.:format) meds#search
                    meds GET    /meds(.:format)                meds#index
                         POST   /meds(.:format)                meds#create
                 new_med GET    /meds/new(.:format)            meds#new
                edit_med GET    /meds/:id/edit(.:format)       meds#edit
                     med GET    /meds/:id(.:format)            meds#show
                         PATCH  /meds/:id(.:format)            meds#update
                         PUT    /meds/:id(.:format)            meds#update
                         DELETE /meds/:id(.:format)            meds#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                              meds#index
                         GET    /                              meds#index
                         POST   /                              meds#create
                         GET    /new(.:format)                 meds#new
                         GET    /:id/edit(.:format)            meds#edit
                         GET    /:id(.:format)                 meds#show
                         PATCH  /:id(.:format)                 meds#update
                         PUT    /:id(.:format)                 meds#update
                         DELETE /:id(.:format)                 meds#destroy
```

What should I change in the routes to fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT: changed url to med_search_path, get new error: `No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"meds"} missing required keys: [:med_id]`. Looks like it's related to the route `/meds/:med_id/search(.:format)`

Comment: try to replace `med_search` to `med_search_path` in your `form_tag` you need to append `_path` while using routes. you also need to either pass `med_id` to the action or change the route from member to collection depending upon your requirement

Comment: I think that might have worked because now I get a different error: `No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"meds"} missing required keys: [:med_id]`. I can see this matches my routes but I don't think I want it set up this way. How can I change the route so that it doesn't require a med_id before I even search?

Comment: going to paste as answer. cant write too much code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** you need to change your form_tag like this

```
 <%= form_tag(search_meds_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
```

**2)** You need to change your route from `member` to collection like this

```
resources :meds do
  collection do
    get 'search' => 'meds#search'
  end
end
```

**3)** Not sure why you need to add `resources :meds, :path => ''` at the bottom again. Incase you dont need it, it is better to remove.

Comment: Getting `unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)` on routes.rb. Updated question with current routes format

Comment: the `end` are complete in the code in answer. is there some `end` extra in your routes file

Comment: Yea I need to add in the devise_for users, the root to the index, and the `resources :meds, :path => '' ` for friendly_id slugs

Comment: sure. im guessing things are working now.? was there some extra end.?

Comment: Still can't get it to run. Can you you please take a look at my answer above? I updated the routes code.

Comment: in your `routes.rb` i can just see an extra `end` the one in the last line. and im expecting it to be the last end of file which is for `Application.routes.draw do` a part from that i cant see any error. just in case you dont need this `=> 'meds#search'` after `get 'search'`. it will work without it as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88834/discussion-between-athar-and-james).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to code up a search but because you put it in the resources block Rails is assuming you're talking about a specific `med`.

Remove the route from the resources block and change it to `get 'meds/search' => 'meds#search'`. That will allow you to use it as just a regular endpoint without Rails complaining that you need an ID.